# SAP Cloud Platform slow build process because of npm install

Tags: npm, gruntjs, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

We use grunt to build our HTML5 Applications on the SAP Hana Cloud Platform. Unfortunately it is very very slow and takes hours sometimes it runs in the 6 minutes timeout to build a small App.

The main reason is that everytime the necessary node packages are installed and npm install runs which takes hours :(

Has anyone experiences with this problem?

Comment: Are you using the trial account? I guess you are talking about the build via grunt/npm inside the SAP Web IDE Fullstack, correct?

Comment: Hi Andre, this issue was fixed, this should not happen anymore.

Comment: @Nabi We have a normal SCP Account and use the SAP Web IDE Full Stack and yes we talk about the build via grunt/npm.

Comment: @MichalK I test it minutes ago and it seems slow again. How do you know that this issue is fixed?

Comment: Because we've seen it in our monitors. Several issues lately. We're still working on making it more stable and with better performance.

Answer (score 2):

After creating some incidents the SAP Cloud Developers Team improve the performance and tell me not to use tilde character in package.json - this leads to many dependencies and maybe a timeout during npm install.

So a **package.json** should look like this when you are working with SAP Web IDE Full-Stack:

```json
{
    "name": "grunt-build",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Grunt build",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt-stripcomments": "0.7.2",
        "grunt-remove-logging-calls": "0.1.2",
        "grunt-postcss": "0.9.0",
        "autoprefixer": "7.2.4",
        "grunt-contrib-less": "1.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "2.2.1",
        "@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build": "1.3.33"
    }
}
```

Comment: we build Applications via mtar and grunt on clientside for now...it is 10 times faster...

Comment: I bet... I was having problems to deploy an app as the build task is triggered before it automatically.

Comment: we deploy via neo tools via CLI https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/1e12331df5e144c7b2cfa9f5db85d065.html

Comment: In my case it's not a cloud deployment